# Sides of the Right angled Triangle in Complex notation.

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles

If $z=a+ib$ is a complex number, then $z, iz, z+iz$ represents sides of the right angled triangle.

I got this result through Cartesian form, i,e. $(a,b)$, $(-b,a)$ and $(a-b,a+b)$ are the vertices of the right angled triangle, then we can easily prove this result.

But how can we interpret this result through amplitude?

I got struck with it.

Let amplitude of $z$ is $\theta$, then amplitude of $iz$ becomes $90+\theta$, therefore it forms right angle. But How to say amplitude of $z+iz$? I got $(90+2\theta)/2$. What is the meaning?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean argument but nevertheless, you have described a right angled isosceles triangle (since $z$ and $i z$ have the same magnitude) hence the other angles are each 45 degrees, which is what the arguments show.

Answer (score 1):

$$z+iz = z(1+i) = \sqrt{2}re^{i(\theta + \pi/4)}$$
It helps to draw a picture. But in this case, since $\theta$ is just a rotation parameter common to all angles, put $\theta=0$. The first point is at $(r,0)$. Second at $(0,r)$. The third at $(r,r)$. Observe that (r,r) has length $\sqrt{2}r$ and angle 45 degrees more than the first point. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: $(r,r), (r,0), (0,r)$ are the vertices of triangle? And $(r,r)$ is the point at right angle? Can we analyze this with vector form?

Comment: Yes they are and yes you may. After all complex numbers are vectors in a sense. Try it and let us know what you find.

Comment: Let $z$ is a vector on $x$-axis, and $iz$ is another vector perpendicular to $z$, then $z+iz$ is the resultant vector between $z$ and $iz$, at 45$\deg$. But where is right angled triangle?

Comment: The vectors don't form the triangle. The point's on their "arrowheads", do. On a side note, while working with vectors that don't have the base point as origin, use AB = OB - OA.

Comment: Ok. Now I clear.. Thank you..